# How to expand wrapped output in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, output

so i was going to cluster some data using kmeans on pycharm it was fine when the data is only hundreds but when data become more than a thousand the output is wrapped and i can only see ... not the whole label for my data, like this :

[screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKKMF.png)

Thanks in advance, 
and sorry for noob question im new at this

Comment: Is this unique to PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

When using Pycharm, try running the code in the python console. This can be done by opening your file and clicking the filename in the top right corner - Edit Configurations. The following window that opens up select under Execution: Run with Python Console. Save this and click the Green start button. You can now see all your variables show up on the right side.

Hope this helps!